# Setting price for an item in quote programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, price, quote

I get the price of the item from external system and I want to update the price of the item in the quote programmatically.

I have this piece of code:

```
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        ...
        $price = getPriceFromSap($item->getProductId);
        $item->setPrice($price);
    }   $quote->save();
```

after that the price is updated correctly in the database, but if I open the cart from the front-end the price is restored to the previous wrong price.
What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Magento recalculates every time the quote is loaded the prices of items and totals.

because since the quote is created until it can pass order, there may be changes in product prices or promotions affecting prices etc.

Comment: Yes it's true, price is always recalculated. I noticed that instead of using method setPrice() I have to call setOrginalCustomPrice().

Comment: Ok is resolved?

Comment: yes, it works correctly.